# Android FireBase Storage Download - How to detect network interruptions?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download larger files using the FirebaseStorage.

My problem: When the connection is lost WHILE downloading there is no error or anything, even if I reconnect, just nothing happens.
When the connection is lost BEFORE the downloads starts the OnFailure-Event fires the following error: "The operation retry limit has been exceeded.".

Why is this not happening when the connection is lost while downloading?

My code:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

       storage.setMaxDownloadRetryTimeMillis(5000);

        StorageReference islandRef = storageRef.child(download_link);

        final File localFile = new File(files_dir, filename);
        islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // Local temp file has been created
                Log.w( "Download", "Download done. File:" + localFile.toString());

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
                Log.w("Download", "Error. Message: " + exception.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage is fault tolerant.  It will retry and resume downloads that are in progress with the hope that network connectivity will return (which is common for mobile devices).

If you want to stop a download when network connectivity is lost, you'll have to detect the loss of connectivity on your own, then cancel the download.

Comment: But when I switch airplane mode on while a file is downloading and then switch it off again it doesn't continuing the download, it just stucks.

Comment: If it doesn't do what you think it ought to do, please file a bug report with your steps to reproduce.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/